# I have removed VirtualBox but I forgot to remove VirtualBox extensions & guest additions

Tags: virtualbox, uninstall, software-uninstall, guest-additions

I removed VirtualBox from Ubuntu 20.04.2 but I had forgot to remove the VirtualBox extensions & guest additions before removing the VirtualBox packages. I have deleted the virtual machine and also removed the virtualbox folders inside .cache and .config directories. Did I left any residue of Virtualbox in my system?

Comment: Also asked at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2464325

Answer (score 2):

The guest additions are *inside* your VMs, not on the VM host.

For the extensions, check if you still have a directory `/usr/lib/virtualbox`.

For a more graphical approach, try this:

- [The QDirStat Unpackaged Files View](https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/blob/master/doc/Unpkg-View.md)
- [The QDirStat Packages View](https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/blob/master/doc/Pkg-View.md)

with

```
qdirstat pkg:/virtual
```

and

```
xhost +
sudo qdirstat unpkg:/
```

Comment: Yeah I have the directory but it's empty (usr/lib/virtualbox)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the guest extensions would be removed with the uninstall of VirtualBox VM's. So you can remove those if you aren't going to use them anymore, or reinstall VirtualBox and delete the VM's from there then do the uninstall again.

Answer (score 0):

To Remove virtualbox and its related packages

```
sudo apt purge virtualbox
```

You can also Unstall virtualbox without removing package by using
`sudo apt remove virtualbox`